# Get Phone name as in Settings -> About phone Android OS option

Tags: android, android-build

I'd like to get that name programatically.

I've already researched android.os.Build and none of its fields seem to help with that.

Is there any way to get that name as wished?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using this snippet -

```
val deviceName = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER
```

This will give you the Mobile Name as `String`. You can use `android.os.Build.MODEL` to get the Model number.

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately I already checked those two fields and it doesn't help.

Comment: Please try this one.
For Activity: `val deviceName  = Settings.Global.getString(contentResolver, "device_name")` and For Fragment: `val deviceName  = Settings.Global.getString(context?.contentResolver, "device_name")`

Comment: sorry for late reply, but I couldn't sooner, already had tested that and it didn't work either, thanks for your interest ayway.